# Gitlab integration correct URL configuration

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I want to use Kiwi TCMS to publish Issues in Gitlab.

Have configured Gitlab to support API key for authentication.

- Posting issue using curl is working fine, like below:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "http://192.168.122.67/api/v4/projects/2/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug"
```

I'm having trouble in putting the right configuration in the Kiwi TCMS form (menu -> admin -> everything else -> remote bug tracker).
Filled in the form like in the image:
[add new bug system form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3vsN.png)

Question is: what's the right syntax of the URL to put in there?

Have looked at documentation about configuring remote bug trackers:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Gitlab

Config is as follows:

- Running Gitlab-CE (14.3.3-ee) and Kiwi TCMS (10.4) locally on the same VM (RHEL 8.4) using Docker-ce.
- Because it's just debugging, the Gitlab is using plain HTTP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration URL is wrong!

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Gitlab says:

> Base_url: URL to a GitLab repository for which we’re going to report
> issues
>
> Api_url:  URL to GitLab instance. Usually gitlab.com!

If `base_url` is `https://gitlab.com/kiwitcms/integration-testing` then `api_url` should be `https://gitlab.com`

https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/pull/2565 adds examples to make the docs more clear.

Comment: This works, perfectly, thanks.